# Mode of each column in MySQL (without explicitly writing column names)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a MySQL query that returns the # of occurrences of the mode of each column individually without explicitly specifying the column names.

Assume the data is:

```
| apples | bananas | oranges |
|   4    |    4    |    3    |
|   2    |    2    |    1    |
|   4    |    3    |    5    |
|   3    |    3    |    5    |
|   4    |    1    |    5    |
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
| mode | count |
|  4   |   3   |
|  3   |   2   |
|  5   |   3   |
```

To get mode for an individual column (apples):

```
SELECT apples AS mode, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY apples
HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY apples);
```

To return column names, I can perform the following:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
```

Inefficiently and with explicit column names, I can achieve the result with UNION:

```
SELECT apples AS mode, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY apples
HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY apples)
UNION 
SELECT bananas AS mode, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY bananas 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY bananas)
UNION 
SELECT oranges AS mode, COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY oranges
HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY oranges)
```

I've been trying a bunch of different queries incorporating the two with GROUP BY and subqueries, but they are a mess, and I'm not making much headway.  I have yet to generate a query to efficiently display the mode of each column with explicitly specifying column names (let alone using column names returned by the second query).

For example (doesn't feel like I'm even on the right track):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM tablename
GROUP BY (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tablename')
HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename
                        GROUP BY (
                            SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'))
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You can't set column or table names dynamically in a query. You need to generate the sql query text dynamically then execute it.

Comment: do you know number of columns? what is your mysql version?

Comment: @ProGu It would have to be dynamic, so the same query could be applied to any table with any number of columns. Version is 8.0

Comment: Selecting `COLUMN_NAME` from information_schema returns a _string_, not an identifier. @Shadow is correct, in SQL, all the syntax and identifiers must be fixed at the time the query is parsed. There is no way to make a query that changes the column it references dynamically during execution. You must do this in two steps: one to format the query, then execute that query.

Comment: I tried for a long time to figure out some hacky way to do this, and came up dry. If I were in your position, I would write a small program that sends one query to get the list of table names, then iterates through the results and sends one additional query for each column. So the result would be for a table with N columns, you programmatically run N+1 queries. I know that's not exactly what you wanted to do, but I think it's the best way given your requirements.

Comment: @MattKorostoff Thanks! I ended up doing something similar in the answer I posted within a MySQL procedure. The procedure grabs the columns and loops through them to write a big UNION query.  So in the end, I call the procedure to create the query and execute it with PREPARE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks not possible to get the expected result using pure SQL in a single query, but it might build a dynamic one like below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS archives.sample_table;
CREATE TABLE archives.sample_table (
  apples INT,
  bananas INT,
  oranges INT
);

INSERT INTO sample_table VALUES 
(   4    ,    4    ,    3    ),
(   2    ,    2    ,    1    ),
(   4    ,    3    ,    5    ),
(   3    ,    3    ,    5    ),
(   4    ,    1    ,    5    )
;

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 9999999;
SET @table_name = 'sample_table';
SET @table_schema = 'archives';
WITH RECURSIVE column_info AS (
  SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION column_index, COLUMN_NAME column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name and TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema
),
query_text AS (
  SELECT i.column_index, CONCAT('SELECT column_name, column_value, counts FROM (  SELECT ''', i.column_name, ''' column_name, `', i.column_name, '` column_value, COUNT(*) counts, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rk  FROM ', @table_name, ' GROUP BY `', i.column_name, '` ) r WHERE rk = 1') single_query
  FROM column_info i
  WHERE i.column_index = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT i.column_index, CONCAT('SELECT column_name, column_value, counts FROM (  SELECT ''', i.column_name, ''' column_name, `', i.column_name, '` column_value, COUNT(*) counts, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rk  FROM ', @table_name, ' GROUP BY `', i.column_name, '` ) r WHERE rk = 1') single_query
  FROM query_text prev
  JOIN column_info i ON prev.column_index + 1 = i.column_index
)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(single_query SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') INTO @stat_query
FROM query_text
;
PREPARE stmt FROM @stat_query
;
EXECUTE stmt
;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
;
```

Sample output

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS archives.sample_table;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE archives.sample_table (  apples INT,  bananas INT,  oranges INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO sample_table VALUES (   4    ,    4    ,    3    ),(   2    ,    2    ,    1    ),(   4    ,    3    ,    5    ),(   3    ,    3    ,    5    ),(   4    ,    1    ,    5    );
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 9999999;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @table_name = 'sample_table';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @table_schema = 'archives';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> WITH RECURSIVE column_info AS (  SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION column_index, COLUMN_NAME column_name  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name and TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema),query_text AS (  SELECT i.column_index, CONCAT('SELECT column_name, column_value, counts FROM (  SELECT ''', i.column_name, ''' column_name, `', i.column_name, '` column_value, COUNT(*) counts, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rk  FROM ', @table_name, ' GROUP BY `', i.column_name, '` ) r WHERE rk = 1') single_query  FROM column_info i  WHERE i.column_index = 1  UNION ALL  SELECT i.column_index, CONCAT('SELECT column_name, column_value, counts FROM (  SELECT ''', i.column_name, ''' column_name, `', i.column_name, '` column_value, COUNT(*) counts, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rk  FROM ', @table_name, ' GROUP BY `', i.column_name, '` ) r WHERE rk = 1') single_query  FROM query_text prev  JOIN column_info i ON prev.column_index + 1 = i.column_index) SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(single_query SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') INTO @stat_query FROM query_text;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @stat_query;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
+-------------+--------------+--------+
| column_name | column_value | counts |
+-------------+--------------+--------+
| apples      |            4 |      3 |
| bananas     |            3 |      2 |
| oranges     |            5 |      3 |
+-------------+--------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I came up with an alternative solution using a stored procedure to create the query, but this looks awesome as well.  The final output is accurate, so much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Per @bill-karwin and @shadow, any attempt to dynamically set the columns in a query are impossible, so I:

1. Created a procedure that generates the query text to produce the modes with UNIONs- it grabs the columns from INFORMATION_SCHEMA and then loops through the columns to create the query:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `column_modes`(OUT strsql TEXT)
BEGIN
    SET @cols = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tablename');

    SET @ct = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename);

    SET @n = 0;
    SET @sql = '';
    WHILE @n < @cols DO
        PREPARE stmt FROM "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tablename' LIMIT ?, 1 INTO @col";
        EXECUTE stmt USING @n;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        SET @sbq = CONCAT('SELECT ',
                          @col,
                          ' AS mode, COUNT(*)/',
                          @ct,
                          ' AS count FROM tablename GROUP BY ',
                          @col,
                          ' HAVING COUNT(*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY ',
                          @col,
                          ')');

        SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,
                          "SELECT '",
                          @col,
                          "' as 'column', GROUP_CONCAT(mode SEPARATOR ',') as mode, GROUP_CONCAT(count SEPARATOR ',') as count FROM (",
                          @sbq,
                          ') temp');

        IF @n != (@cols - 1) THEN
            SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ' UNION ');
        END IF;
        SET @n = @n + 1;
    END WHILE;

    -- SELECT @sql; 
    SET strsql = @sql;
END
```

2. Executed the query with PREPARE:

```
CALL column_modes(@thisvar);
SELECT @thisvar;
PREPARE stmt FROM @thisvar;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Thanks very much to @ProGu for a second solution as well.